# Process text-only in HTML and put back in place

Tags: javascript

I need to find all text within a div, do some text processing and then put processed text back in place.

Sample html (but it can be anything):

```
<div id="divToProcess">
    <div>Some text here</div>
    <div id="id1">some more <span class="class2">text</span> and more text</div>
    <div class="class1">some more text <a href="xxxxxx">link text</a><div>
</div>
```

So on the above I need to loop all elements inside the divToProcess, get all text (in the above case I need to get "Some text here", "some more ", "text", " and more text", "some more text ", "link text"), and then after I processes the text (make some changes based on the text) I need to put it back in place (with the changes).

I cannot figure out how to do the loop in order to get all text from all elements. I prefer a non-jQuery solution but will take anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a flexible approach, using callbacks:

```
function replaceTextNodes(node, callback) {
    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
            replaceTextNodes(node.childNodes[i], callback);
        }
    } else if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        node.textContent = callback(node.textContent);
    }
}

replaceTextNodes(document.getElementById("divToProcess"), function (text) {
    return text + text;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QAyAM/

This would keep all event handlers etc unmodified, as you probably wanted.

Edit: A function which allows replacing text with HTML. I'm not 100% sure if this approach is correct/good, if anyone has any comments, please DO comment, so we all can learn. :)

Test HTML:

```
<div id="divToProcess">
    <div>Some text here</div>
    <div id="id1">so hello me more <span class="class2">text</span> and more text</div>
    <div class="class1">some more text <a href="xxxxxx">link text</a>
        hello!! hello
    <div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function replaceTextNodesWithHTML(node, callback) {
    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
            replaceTextNodesWithHTML(node.childNodes[i], callback);
        }
    } else if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        var parentNode = node.parentNode;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = callback(node.textContent);
        var childNodes = [].slice.call(div.childNodes);
        if (childNodes.length > 0) {
            parentNode.replaceChild(childNodes[childNodes.length - 1], node);
            for (var i = childNodes.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
                parentNode.insertBefore(childNodes[i], childNodes[i + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

replaceTextNodesWithHTML(document.getElementById("divToProcess"), function (text) {
    return text.replace(/hello/g, "<a href='#'>Hello!</a>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tXS2v/1/

Comment: This works great but only if the "processed" text is also just text. Any idea how to make this work if the processed text contains html? For example if "some more text " in the original example becomes "some  <a id='id1'>more</a> text " ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to strip the tags you can do the following:

```
var div = document.getElementById('divToProcess');
div.innerHTML = div.innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "";
var nodes = document.getElementById('divToProcess').childNodes;
for(i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{
    text += text.innerHTML()+"<br/>";
}
```

I haven't checked syntax though, but is this something you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

A basic recursive approach.

```
function process(el){
    if(el.nodeType === 3) {    
       // process text node   
        if(el.data){
            el.data = processText(el.data);   
        }
    } else {
        // process children if any
        var children = el.childNodes;

        for(var i = 0; i<children.length; i++){
            process(children[i]);   
        }
    }
}

function processText(text){
    return text.replace("e","*");
}

var top = document.getElementById("top");
process(top);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ud78Y/